# Referencing a file from inside a jar

Tags: java

How do I reference a file from inside the jar in the packages? Because right now it's only looking for the file in the directory that the jar file is in.

I have packed the file inside of the jar correctly, but I'm not sure how to refer to it.

Comment: put your code here and say where are the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"?  Jars need to go into `lib` subdirectory and you need to update your classpath in the manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("..../.../...");
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("..../.../...");
```

Either absolute ("/...") or relative to the getClass.

Comment: I'm using: 
   URL url = this.class.getResource("configure.dll");
   new a(url.toString(), output);
and it's giving me a null because it can't find the file, but the directory is correct

Comment: If getResource returns null, it did not find the file. You can open the jar with 7Zip, WinZip or so. Then look in the directory path equal to the package path of the class of getClass. Also all is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

See Class.getResourceAsStream API